# Do we need an annotated "good questions" page?

Tags: discussion

Do we need an annotated "good questions" page?

A lot, not all, of the downvoting here (and I'm not referring specifically to my issues) seems to be based on something like the format, form, of the question. So simplicity or a rant, to the exclusion of motivation and clear reasoning, etc..

Could directing question askers to "good questions" (and not just popular / trendy ones) help our users?

Comment: I like the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new here. I'm still practically blind to what's going on behind the scenes, but I read the help topics .

Curation may be difficult to implement; curators aren't always optimally informed. I've worked both ways, and I don't think that the results from my participation in curated discussions turned out better than the other ones. It seems to me that the benefits accrued depend on who's saying what and with what intent, not on curation.

That's not an answer, it's a story and a conjecture, but I don't know how anyone could produce *right answer* to this...